# CreateDataSource not working with WCF and a stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am trying to override the connection string in a WCF DataService with `CreateDataSource`. This seems to work fine for simple requests for tables, but when I try to use a stored procedure it fails...it's always trying to use the original datasource set up for the SP when i worked with the .edmx file.

My code is:

```
string mConnectionString; 
mConnectionString = ConfgurationManager.ConnectionStrings["D7SG_DEVEntities"].ConnectionString;
return new SGEntities(mConnectionString);`
```

The error which occurs is

> *The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid.*

Anyone know how to make this work with a stored procedure ? (This procedure works fine when used with the hard-coded string in `web.config`)

Comment: Can you please also show us your service's config file? The error message would indicate that something with that connection string is wrong - does it look quite different from your other connection string (in web.config) that works?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the service operation which invokes the stored procedure? Store procedures are not supported automatically by WCF Data Services, so unless you do so explicitly they will not go through CreateDataSource.

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT here is the call {  [WebGet]
        public List<spMobile_GetAllLocationData_Result> getAllLocationData (string thisLat, string thisLng)
        {
            SGEntities entities2 = new SGEntities();
            return entities2.spMobile_GetAllLocationData(Convert.ToDouble(thisLat), Convert.ToDouble(thisLng)).ToList();
        }

Comment: I cant figure out how to format code on this site! Sorry.

Comment: @marc_s The config strings are exactly the same.. only the name has been changed (and the database name, of course)

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @marc_s I am sorry.. pretty new to this site and having a little trouble figuring out the rules, even after looking at the excessively long faq.

Comment: We all live and learn every day - no worries :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service operation, you're creating the SGEntities without passing in the modified connection string. So it will pick the default connection string from your configuration. In order for this to work you can use this.CurrentDataSource instead of creating a new instance of the SGEntities in your service operation implementation. That will go through the CreateDataSource and should pick up the new connection string.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much, I searched everywhere for that information.